# MS Access unable to delete row added using Java app and Ucanaccess driver

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am working on project to update an application that previously used sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver to access a MS-Access Database. The Application currently works fine, but newly Inserted rows (created by the Java App) from one table in the database show the error.

```
'cannot open database ". It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt'
```

when Deleting the row in MS Access.

Below is the Suspected stack trace, calling a select statement from the mentioned table, and Query statement.

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: RECNUMBER
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:210)
at TestApp.sheetPanelMouseClicked(TestApp.java:3711)
at TestApp.access$200(TestApp.java:23)
at TestApp$4.mouseClicked(TestApp.java:393)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

and

```
queryString ="Select * from SampleTable Where recNumber = " + recNumber +
 " And primary_id = '" + sampIDText.getText() + "' Primarydate =" + "#" + primaryDate + "#";
```

I believe it is coming from the where clause 'recNumber'

Comment: Is your application using a `CREATE TABLE` statement to create the table before you insert rows into it?

Comment: All Tables have already been created, here is the query string I that is inserting records, using stmt. executeUpdate (would .execute be of better use?)
``
   qryString =  "Insert into SampleTable (sample_id, sample_date, sample_time, sample_seq) " +
                                    "values ('" + sampIDText.getText() + "'," + "#" + focDate + "#" + "," + "#" + timeText + "#" + ",'" + mpText + "')";

Comment: Please **edit** your question with more information, don't use comments for that. Also please stop concatenating values into a query string, it is unsafe and leaves you open to SQL injection and can be easily mitigated using prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider using prepared statements, though the DB accessed is local, along with the application, and does not hold private information.

Comment: You could try replacing the current version of Jackcess in your classpath with version 2.1.9. That update to Jackcess has fixed similar errors in other circumstances.

Comment: Thank you Gord, I will try that and comment back. I had been using Jackcess 2.1.6. Additionally, selecting repair database in Access fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be interested to hear if Jackcess 2.1.9 does the trick for you, too.

Comment: Hi Gord, the using Jackcess 2.1.9 works. I am now able to delete rows from the MS Access table after running the program! I am still running into net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: RECNUMBER In which the select query is running Select * from map_time Where recNumber = 1 And sample_id = 'WL' And Fdate =#12/22/2017# is there an alternative to recNumber? I could not find much reference to it aside from it, it might have been used by the previous JDBC:ODBC driver

Comment: @JonathanValdivieso - Thanks for the update. Glad to hear that the Jackcess upgrade helped. As for the "RECNUMBER" error, it is almost certainly an unrelated issue that is specific to your database. You may want to ask about it in the UCanAccess [help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/).